# run GUI from different class in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I created a GUI class and a demo class.
the demo class is calling to the GUI. I would like to run the GUI in a different thread.

**GUI Class**

```
public class UserGui extends JFrame {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UserGui frame = new UserGui();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
 }
```

**Demo Class:**

```
public class NNDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserGui gui = new UserGui();
        gui.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: First, never & we do mean NEVER interact with any Swing componet from any Thread other then the Event Dispathing Thread.  Secondly, what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class UserGui extends JFrame {
    public UserGui() {}

    public void showGui() {
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                  final UserGui GUI = new UserGui();
                  GUI.showGui();
             }

        });
    } 
}
```

Comment: nice, but how can I call to method from the GUI class

Comment: see editing. its just one example. there are more. in this example you have the possibility to get a static reference of your frame in each other classes.

Comment: @kleopatra u r right sorry. the whole gui should be created in a new thread. so yes the initializing of the UserGui object has to be moved to run.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** `Event Dispatcher Thread` (EDT) is responsible for the Gui.

**2.** `main()` method in GUI applications are **not long lived**, and after scheduling the construction of GUI in the Event Dispatcher Thread it exits.. So now its the Responsibility of the EDT to handle the GUI.

This is how i like to do the above example:

```
public class UserGui extends JFrame {

    public UserGui() {

      // You can set the size here, initialize the state and handlers.
    }


}



public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

              new UserGui().setVisible(true);

             }

        });
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is the code automatically generated by Net beans for running the frame in a separated thread

```
     public static void main(String[] args){

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new BoardPlay().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
   }
```